# How to factor the polynomial $6x^3 - 13x^2y + 4y^3 $?

Tags: polynomials

I have difficulties in factorizing the following polynomial in two variables : $6x^3 - 13x^2y + 4y^3 $. Thanks to a calculator I know that $6x^3 - 13x^2y + 4y^3 = (2y-3x)(2y-x)(y+2x)$, but I have no idea how to find this factorization. Is there any method to factor such polynomials ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use the rational root theorem, regarding this as a cubic in $x$, to find possible roots $x$ as functions of $y$.

Comment: it might be simpler to factor $6x^3 - 13 x^2 + 4$ and then see that you can multiply the constants by $y.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has homogeneity, a very strong property. Let me turn around my comment, let $$ w = y/x. $$
Divide the original by $x^3.$ You now need merely factor 
$$ 4 w^3 - 13 w + 6.  $$
This has rational roots, and so on. Not difficult.

Comment: Thanks for showing me this trick !

Answer (score 1):

Let $x =ty$

\begin{eqnarray}
6x^3 - 13x^2y + 4y^3 &=& y^3(6t^3 -13t^2+4)\\
&=& y^3(6t^3 -12t^2-t^2+4)\\
&=& y^3(6t^2(t -2)-(t-2)(t+2))\\
&=& y^3(t-2)(6t^2-t-2)...\\
 \end{eqnarray}